# BrowserSync. Можно ли открыть сайт на планшете/смартфоне?

Tags: browsersync

Каким образом при помощи плагина BrowserSync открыть localhost на внешнем устройстве?

По Ip не выходит:

```
 ------------------------------------
 Local: http://localhost:3000
 External: http://**.**.56.92:3000
 ------------------------------------
```

Возможно, нужно сделать что-то еще, или эта фишка вообще не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное, чтобы устройство было в той же сети wi-fi. Потом прописываем экстернал ip